# How can I take screenshots on 5-second intervals with Flutter background code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background, screenshot

It seems I can't take screenshots outside the Flutter app using any given library. I have used screenshot and native_screenshot package and also the repaint boundary method.
To clarify, I want to monitor user activity by taking screenshots, where my flutter app will be running in the background, and taking the screenshots of the current user activity every 5 seconds.
I have successfully deployed a background service, but when I try to take a screenshot the native_screenshot package simply denies it, and the screenshot package takes the snap of the app screen again and again which makes sense as I wrapped the main page scaffold with the Screenshot widget.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't take a screenshot in Android if your app isn't in the foreground.  That's to prevent you from taking pictures of his PMs, online banking info, etc.

Comment: is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: If your phone is rooted there's a few hacks.  If you want to release it as a play store app, no.  And expect if you find a way and Google discovers it, they'll try to close the loophole.

Comment: How about if I use some kind of screen recording? Screen recording apps are all over the playstore. Is it possible if I record the screen with a background service and then just sample some random frames for what I am trying to do?